# What is the best way to download updates to the game made in Unity

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

We are currently working on one Unity 3D game, which is already on production. We are working on upgrading the features and adding some new stuff to the game.

The development also includes some fixes to the current version.

**Whenever we do changes and build our game the project's/ game's asset bundle and other resources will get changed**

Current Method.

1. The game upon launch runs one patcher which calls one service on the ftp server.
2. The game client also sends a list of game files it has in it game root in an xml format to the server.
3. The server compares the filelist of client and a filelist of its original directory to check for any updates.
4. If it finds it sends the updatable filelist to the client in response.
5. The client on the game side first downloads all the required files and the game will be launched.

The Problem

1. We are continuously working on fixing various bugs, improvements, new features. We want to push all those in a very frequent daily basis.
2. As you know our method of patcher, the number and size of files which need updates are very high. The sizes of all the files also matter.
3. Even with small changes to the scene and existing resources which is very less, the amount of download required from client is very high..

What I need

1. A possible best solution that only requires very small amount of download with only updated assets.
2. Any good approach is appreciated.

Friends please share your ideas.

Comment: What files get changed? How are they changed? How do you determine whether a resource file on the server is different from the client? How do you transfer the files? Do you check whether the app has already downloaded the files to a user-writable directory and should in fact check the downloaded version against the server's rather than the files in the app bundle? Target platform is windows? Or are you just developing on windows?

Comment: When you make so thinkme fixes in the game, or update the texture or any asset which is development. If I thinks that the changes are good then I will build the game and ,move it production. Production in the sense I'll be putting all the game files in an ftp server where client downloads it.

Comment: Yes the downloads are happening. But upon updating the game many resource / asset bundles will get affected with only minor changes / tweaks. But with big file sizes. This the problem.